# Using the definition of limit show that $\lim_{x→x_0} x^3=x_0^3$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

We want to show that $∀ϵ>0,∃δ_ϵ(x_0)>0$ such that if $0<|x−x_0|<δ_ϵ(x_0)$, then $|x^3−x_0^3|<ϵ$.

$|x^3−x_0^3|=|(x-x_0)(x+x_0)^2|=|x-x_0||x^2 + xx_0 + x_0^2|$. Here we have $|x-x_0|<δ_ϵ(x_0)$.

Assume $δ_ϵ(x_0)=1$. Then, $|x-x_0| < 1$, and $|x|-x_0 ≤ |x-x_0| < 1$, implying that $|x| < x_0 +1$, implying that $$|(x^2 + xx_0 + x_0^2)| ≤ |x|^2 + |x|x_0 + x_0^2 < 3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1$$.

So, take any ϵ>0, then $$|x^3−x_0^3|<ϵ$$   if,

$$|x-x_0| < \frac{ϵ}{3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1}$$.

Let $$δ_ϵ(x_0) = min\{1, \frac{ϵ}{3x_0^2 + 3x_0 + 1}\}$$ and we are done.

Could you please verify my proof?

Comment: Not likely many will have the nerve to try to understand all that written that way. Please use MathJaX here to type mathematics

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your posts.  This is hard to read.

Comment: The first line is wrong.  We want to show  $|x^3-x_0^3|<\delta_\varepsilon.$

Comment: No apology necessary.  Welcome to MSE.

Comment: I would have edited myself if that we all that was wrong, but I wasn't sure.  You say $|x^3−x_0^3|=|(x-x_0)(x+x_0)^2|$, however $x^3-x_0^3=(x-x_0)(x^2+x x_0+x_0^2)$

Comment: Line 3, what you want to prove is that $|\delta_\epsilon| \leqslant 1$ then for all $x$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta_\epsilon$, $|(x^2 + 2xx_0 + x_0^2)| ≤ |x|^2 + 2|x|x_0 + x_0^2 < 4x_0^2 + 4x_0 + 1$. The proof is correct if you assume $|\delta_\epsilon| \leqslant 1$ instead of $|\delta_\epsilon| = 1$

Comment: @OlivierRoche but why is that? we first assumed that it is equal to one, found the other solution for it, and finally took the minimum of both to insure that whatever we get will be the lowest of both solutions.

Comment: @AhmedAly It would improve clarity. Explicit is better than implicit.

In fact, the most elegant way would probably be to claim that $|x-x_0| < 1 \Longrightarrow |(x^2 + 2xx_0 + x_0^2)| ≤ |x|^2 + 2|x|x_0 + x_0^2 < 4x_0^2 + 4x_0 + 1$. Prove it like you did, and go on from there.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: It is $$x^3-x_0^3=(x-x_0)(x^2+xx_0+x_0^2)$$